# 401 Unauthorized Dynamics CRM REST API

Tags: rest

I'm trying to learn REST and run some tests against our Dynamics CRM online tenant. I've followed numerous how-to's to configure the Azure AD client id, secret, and configure the CRM role. However, when running some tests in Insomnia, I'm getting 401 Unauthorized after getting the token. Any thoughts on this? The screenshot is attached.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lOyj.png)

Comment: you should share your code , so we can help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What code would you like shared? I shared the screenshot of the api call. Thank you.

Comment: At StackOverflow you are required to share your code ,then we are only able to help you.